# Javascript code not working properly in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

index.html.erb

```
<div id="app-back-button">
  <%= link_to image_tag("back.png",:border => 0), 'javascript:history.go(-1);' %>
</div>
```

Above mentioned code triggers back action when back button is clicked.

index.html.erb

Below mentioned code is used to hide and show the div contents.

```
<a href="#">LINK</a>

<div id = "test">

    <h2>Import Statements</h2>

    <%= form_tag import_xvaziris_path, multipart: true do %>
    <%= file_field_tag :file %>
    <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
    <% end %>

</div>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("div#test").hide();
    $("a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("div#test").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Now the problem is that when I click the back button, it triggers hide/show functionality and do not go backwards.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Full index view is as below;

index.html.erb

```
<div id="content_header">
    <h1 id="main_heading">XTEP Vaziri Statement</h1>

    <div id="app-back-button">
        <%= link_to image_tag("back.png",:border => 0), 'javascript:history.go(-1);' %>
    </div>

</div>

<br>

<a href="#">...</a>

<div id = "test">

    <h2>Import Statements</h2>

    <%= form_tag import_xvaziris_path, multipart: true do %>
    <%= file_field_tag :file %>
    <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
    <% end %>

</div>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("div#test").hide();
    $("a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("div#test").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@WesFoster has explained you the reason. But, if you remove the `preventDefault()`, it would still be "toggling" your `div`. Even though your page goes back. That's because you are selecting ALL anchor tags on your page.

A better way would be to select specific toggle link and add toggle functionality to that specific element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div#test").hide();

  $("a.form-toggle-link").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("div#test").toggle();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="form-toggle-link">LINK</a>

<div id="test">
  <h2>Import Statements</h2>
  ...
</div>

<div id="app-back-button">
  <a href="javascript:history.go(-1);">Another link</a>
</div>
```

---

**Full index.html.erb:**

```
<div id="content_header">
  <h1 id="main_heading">XTEP Vaziri Statement</h1>
  <div id="app-back-button">
    <%=link_to image_tag("back.png", :border=>0), 'javascript:history.go(-1);' %>
  </div>
</div>

<br>

<!--           |=== HERE  -->
<a href="#" class="toggle-form">...</a>

<div id="test">
  <h2>Import Statements</h2>
  <%=f orm_tag import_xvaziris_path, multipart: true do %>
    <%=f ile_field_tag :file %>
    <%=s ubmit_tag "Import" %>
  <% end %>
</div>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("div#test").hide();

    //    | === HERE
    $("a.toggle-form").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $("div#test").toggle();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, but i am unable to get the result as expected. If paste my index.html.erb full view so that you could guide what will go where.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much.great job!

Answer (score 0):

It's not going "back" because you have prevented it from doing so:

```
# This prevents the link from executing
event.preventDefault();
```

Therefore, the `javascript:history.go(-1);` is not executing.

Remove the `preventDefault()` and it will allow you to go "back" as intended.

Comment: Thanks Sir, It is working but when I click on LINK , it functions properly at the same time it takes me to top of the page.